# Linear programming of sperner lemma

Tags: operations-research

How can you formulate the 2-D proof of Sperner lemma as a linear programming problem?

I know that you have to divide the triangle up into smalled triangles with the original triangle having vertices labelled 0,1,2. However, I have no idea what to use as constraints or what to make the objective function. Please help answer this question.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Sperner's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma) sketches a proof of the two-dimensional (triangulation) case, but does not make a connection with linear programming.  Instead the proof is based on the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), qpplied to a graph derived from the triangulation.